# Set a variable to number of rows that meet a criterion based on a group by without using temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to do what I'm doing below without using a temp table?

I need to return the number of rows that have a count<>1 based on a grouped by query.  I tried to do this with a cte, but I believe the issue there is that the first statement at the end of a cte must be a select statement

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp
select * into #temp
from
(
select 
        count(*) as cnt
        ,aColumnToGroupBy
from 
        TableA
where 
        aDifferentColumn=1
group by 
        aColumnToGroupBy
)data

DECLARE @DUB INT
SET @DUB = (select COUNT(*) from #temp where cnt<>1)

PRINT @DUB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `HAVING` clause:

```
DECLARE @DUB INT
SET @DUB = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM (
              SELECT aColumnToGroupBy, COUNT(*)
              FROM TableA
              WHERE aDifferentColumn = 1
              GROUP BY aColumnToGroupBy
              HAVING COUNT(*) <> 1) AS t)
```

`@DUB` variable will be set equal to the number of `aColumnToGroupBy` groups having a population that is different to `1`.